# node express proxy-middleware handle redirect

Tags: node.js, redirect, proxy

I am trying to use [proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-middleware) to forward to https://npmcdn.com/ which works when I specify the final path, but when I specify shorthand urls, they are redirected to `/` of the local server, so return a 404.

```
app.use('/cdn', proxy('https://npmcdn.com/'));
```

Then trying to hit local server...

```
$.get('/cdn/lodash@4.9.0'); // works as expected
$.get('/cdn/lodash'); // is redirected to `/lodash@4.9.0` so gets 404
```

How can I handle redirects with my proxy server so that it is redirected to the correct remote url?

### Update:

@hassansin, thanks for the pointer. It looks like I can fix my problem by adding a condition to handle when absolute path is given without domain, do you think it will break anything else?

```
if (((statusCode > 300 && statusCode < 304) || statusCode === 201) && location) {
    // absolute path with domain
    if(location.indexOf(options.href) > -1) {
      headers.location = location.replace(options.href, slashJoin('/', slashJoin((options.route || ''), '')));
    // absolute path without domain
    } else if(location[0] === '/') {
      headers.location = options.href.replace(/\/$/,'') + headers.location;
    }
}
```

### Update 2:

@hassansin, how about this..?

```
    // absolute path without domain
    } else if(location[0] === '/' && req.originalUrl.slice(req.url.length*-1) === req.url) {
      headers.location = req.originalUrl.slice(0, req.url.length*-1) + headers.location;
    }
```

Comment: should work, except it would now redirect to `https://npmcdn.com/lodash@4.9.0` instead of `proxyserver.com/cdn/lodash@4.9.0`

Comment: @hassansin, good point. I updated my question again, this time with a more circuitous method by stripping req.url from req.originalUrl, then adding headers.location. It appears to work for me, can you see any problems? Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https://npmcdn.com/lodash` redirects to `https://npmcdn.com/lodash@4.9.0` with 302 status and `location:/lodash@4.9.0` header. `proxy-middleware` doesn't seem to handle relative 302 redirects properly. [It only handles absolute redirects](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-proxy-middleware/blob/effb1d5bb101c24ebb8d6298fd7a304e19c81085/index.js#L60-L64).

Comment: I updated my question with a potential fix, could you look at it and tell me if you think it makes sense to implement? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will include the baseUrl back on the redirect location

- `/cdn/lodash` will redirect to `/lodash@4.9.0`

  - `userResHeaderDecorator` will rewrite it to `/cnd/lodash@4.9.0`
- request to `/cdn/lodash@4.9.0` will work properly

```js
app.use(
  '/$BASEURL',
  proxy(`http://somewhere-else.com`, {
    userResHeaderDecorator(headers, userReq, userRes) {
      if (userRes.statusCode.toString().startsWith('30') 
        && !headers.location.includes('://'))
        headers.location = userReq.baseUrl + headers.location
      return headers
    },
  })
)
```